# error : com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I want to sync my **build.gradle** file I have got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: `com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 3`

this is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.inspius.read247'
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION as int
        versionCode VERSION_CODE as int
        versionName VERSION_NAME

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SUPPORT_PACKAGE_VERSION}"

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton-library:1.8.2@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    compile project(':libraries:pulltorefreshLib')
    compile project(':libraries:Simple Facebook')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':libraries:libraryPhotoView')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    //parse
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'

}
```

What should I do?

Comment: call `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'` Let me feedback

Comment: you can comment `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'`

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

Comment: comment out `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'`

Comment: please debug . `duplicate entry meaning same type library calling`

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3